# why should we use Exception as a superclass, why not BaseException

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, superclass

In python, whenever we are writing User-defined exception, we have to extend it from class `Exception`. 
my question is why can't we extend it from `BaseException` which is super-class of exception hierarchy and `Exception` is also subclass of `BaseException`.

Comment: Of course you can. Whether you *should*  is a different question. Python is just trying to make it a bit harder for you to shoot yourself in the foot, but if you insist, nobody's keeping you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BaseException` includes things like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`, which use the exception mechanism, but which most people shouldn't be catching. It's analogous to `Throwable` in Java, if you're familiar with that. Things that derive directly from `BaseException` are generally intended to shut down the system while executing `finally` blocks and context manager `__exit__` methods to release resources.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Python2 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), there are four exceptions that are derivatives of `BaseException`:

```
BaseException
 +-- SystemExit
 +-- KeyboardInterrupt
 +-- GeneratorExit
 +-- Exception
```

The three that are not `Exception` are not actually errors, which means in general you don't want to catch them as if they are errors.  `BaseException` was added in Python2.5 (before that, there was no `BaseException` and the other exceptions were subclassed from `Exception`).